# I pressed ctrl with - and now my terminal view become so small, how to recover?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I thought ctrl with + should work, but it doesn't.

How could I recover it and zoom out the views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To zoom in, just press the following keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (without the numeric keypad)

To recover your initial settings, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (without the numeric keypad)

Alternatively, you can use the `gnome-terminal` View menu to perform such operations:

[image]

Comment: why zoom in need no 'shift' and zoom out need one? It's confusing!

Comment: On my azerty (french) keyboard, `-` does not need shift (but 6 does), may be the same for qwerty

Comment: Qwerty `-` is below `_` hence no need for the shift key as well

Comment: @Zen `-` can be types by hitting the key `-`. `+` can be typed by holding Shift, and then hitting `=`. If you only press "Ctrl + `+`" as you say, then you actually type `Ctrl + `=`. With the Numpad, you do not have that issue though.

Answer (score 2):

As the location of `+` and `-` can be very different when changing keyboard language or layout, it may be hard to find.
In some terminals, there is an easy and save alternative:

In KDE's terminal `konsole`, and maybe others, Control+MouseWheelUp and -Down work too for changing font size.

Answer (score 1):

Press `CTRL + 0` to go to normal size. That should fix it.